# making var value available in button click

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

how would I get the value of domain in  var mydomain = collectedDomains[i].email_domain be available in the later button click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#email_address').blur(function(){

        var emailAddress = $('#email_address').val().split('@');
        var domain = emailAddress[1];
        var tagMap = {};
           var i = null;
        for (i = 0; collectedDomains.length > i; i += 1) {
            var mydomain = collectedDomains[i].email_domain;               
        }

        var hasTag = function(tagName) {
            return tagMap[tagName];
        };  

    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        //need the value of var mydomain available here
    });
});
```

Comment: javascript does not have block scope, so it should be available in your click event as it is.

Comment: Your question can't be answered.Your code and question are very unclear.There are multiple `collectedDomains[i].email_domain`, which one you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope issue. You just have to define the variable you want to use outside of both of the functions that reference it. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mydomain = null;

    $('#email_address').blur(function(){

        var emailAddress = $('#email_address').val().split('@');
        var domain = emailAddress[1];
        var tagMap = {};
        var i = null;

        for (i = 0; collectedDomains.length > i; i += 1) {
            mydomain = collectedDomains[i].email_domain;               
        }

        var hasTag = function(tagName) {
            return tagMap[tagName];
        };  
    });

    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        //mydomain equals whatever you set it to in the .blur call
    });
});
```

Comment: You moved the OP's click handler! Why did you do that?

Comment: you should not use 
 var domain = emailAddress[1]; as it will be shadowing outer variable

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var domain;
// domain is now available in all the functions inside ready block
$('#email_address').blur(function(){

        var emailAddress = $('#email_address').val().split('@');
        var tagMap = {};
        var i = null;
        //See here its without var
        domain = emailAddress[1];
        for (i = 0; collectedDomains.length > i; i += 1) {
            var mydomain = collectedDomains[i].email_domain;               
        }

        var hasTag = function(tagName) {
            return tagMap[tagName];
        };  
   });
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        //need the value of var mydomain available here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in as a variable somewhere in the scope:

```
$('#email_address').blur(function(){

        var emailAddress = $('#email_address').val().split('@'),
            domain = emailAddress[1],
            tagMap = {},
            i = null,
            mydomain; //VIOLA!

        for (i = 0; collectedDomains.length > i; i += 1) {
            mydomain = collectedDomains[i].email_domain;               
        }

        var hasTag = function(tagName) {
            return tagMap[tagName];
        };  

        $('#Button1').click(function(){
            //need the value of var mydomain available here
        });
});
```

Comment: @Engineer why doesn't it make sense??

Comment: @Neal: I think we were editting at the same time... I'll stop now.

Comment: Because JS has function scope,and not block scope

Comment: it will add onclick handler on each and every blur and so end up with multiple execution of codes as well as event will not file if its not blured

Comment: @Engineer and in this example The click on the button is in the **same** scope as `mydomain`

Comment: @Neal Yes, it was there and before.See the OP's question again